# Relative marginal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a word in the language of group theory. If $G$ is a group, then $w(G)$ is the subgroup generated by all values of $w$ taken at elements of $G$; $w(G)$ is the *verbal subgroup of $G$* corresponding to $w$.

Philip Hall defined the “dual” concept of *marginal subgroup* associated to $w$. The marginal subgroup of $G$ associated to $w$, $w^*(G)$, is the collection of all $a\in G$ such that for all $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G$ and each $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, 
$$\begin{array}{rl}
w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},ag_i,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n) &= w(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1},g_ia,g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n)\\ 
&= w(g_1,\ldots,g_n).
\end{array}$$
It turns out that this collection is in fact a subgroup.

Verbal subgroups are functorial and fully invariant; if $H\leq G$, then $w(H)\leq w(G)$. Marginal subgroups are characteristic. Note that the verbal subgroup is *generated by*, but not necessarily equal to, the set of values of the word, whereas the set of marginal elements already forms the marginal subgroup.

For example, if $w(x,y) = [x,y]$, then the verbal subgroup $w(G)$ is the commutator subgroup, and the marginal subgroup $w^*(G)$ is the center. If $w(x)=x^n$, then the verbal subgroup is the subgroup generated by the $n$th powers, and the marginal subgroup is the subgroup of central elements of exponent $n$. **Note:** not quite. See comments.

I’m wondering whether:

> Is there a notion of “relative margin” of a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $w^*_G(H)$, such that
>
> 1. $w^*_G(G)=w^*(G)$;
> 2. for $w=[x,y]$, $w^*_G(H)=C_G(H)$.

There are several possibilities to make this happen, but before I start exploring I want to see if this “relative” notion has already been considered.

Comment: About $w^{\ast}(G)$ for $w(x) = x^n$: if $G$ is a non-Abelian group of exponent $n$, then $w^{\ast}(G) = G$ has non-central elements. In general, the central elements whose order divide $n$ lie in $w^{\ast}(G)$ which in turn lies the set of elements of $C_G(w(G))$ with order dividing $n$.

Comment: @LucGuyot: Thanks; I always get tripped with that one, though the claim that it is the central elements of exponent $n$ has appeared a number of times...

Answer (score 1):

L.-C. Kappe and M. Meriano dealt with a similar problem, see

[Meriano's Groups St. Andrews 2013 slides](http://www.groupsstandrews.org/2013/slides/Meriano.pdf)

They defined certain subgroups ${}^*w_2(g)$ for a two-variable word $w$ which seem to be what you've asked for; just take

$${}^*w_2(H)=\bigcap_{h\in H} {}^*w_2(h).$$

I'm sure this can be adapted to $n$-variable words.

Comment: In fact, this is the source of my question (well, talking to Kappe herself on something related to this).